# Repo init fails when trying to initialize the merge request source

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, gitlab

I am trying to clone the merge request sources by using:

`repo init -u http://gitlab.com/mn/project1.git -b refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/* -m tools/manifests/math.xml --no-clone-bundle`

but facing the following **error** `fatal: Invalid refspec '+refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/*:refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/*'`

**and also i tried**   `repo init -u http://gitlab.com/mn/project1.git -b  merge-requests/5/head -m tools/manifests/math.xml --no-clone-bundle`

but again i am facing following **error** `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/merge-requests/5/head`

my xml file looks like below:

```
<manifest>
  <remote name="MN" fetch="http://gitlab.com/mn" />
  <project name="proj1" remote="MN" path="proj1" revision="re1.3.0" />
  <project name="proj2" remote="MN" path="proj2" revision="re1.4.0" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using the gitlab plugin?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By trying the following command i am able to clone the merge request sources from gitlab

`repo init -u https://gitlab.com/gp1/p1.git -b refs/merge-requests/<merge_request_id>/head -m tools/manifests/math.xml --no-clone-bundle`